# Struts2 jQuery Plugin Autocompleter renders HTML with style attributes <== changing this?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, struts2

I'm using the Struts2 jQuery plugin 2.1 and render an autocompleter in my JSP. Here's the code:

```
<s:form id="search-form" action="search" theme="simple">
         <s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonlanguages"/>
          <div>
        <sj:autocompleter 
            cssClass="bgstandardelement empty"
            id="languages" 
            name="echo"
            href="%{remoteurl}" 
            delay="50"
            value="Search..."
        />

        <input type="submit" id="search-button" value="GO" />
        </div>
    </s:form>
```

No matter what theme I set the autocompleter-form to, the HTML rendered for the list I output is always an unordered list with a style element that I cannot override. It has the following stype-attribute:

```
style='z-index: 1; top: 242px; left: 926px; display: none; width: 256px';
```

As I want another outfit for my list, this doesn't work. Putting in the following attribute has no effect:

```
cssStyle="width:115px!important;"
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clear things up: I guess this must have been an error on my part. Using theme="simple" should make all styling go away, so you can do everything yourself with CSS. I might also have had a theme set in the rendered struts2-head element and took that away. Sorry for asking, it works now.